# Insert html Ad block dynamically in my posts in php

Tags: php, string

Thats my scenario: I want to add some ad blocks dynamically each 3 or 4 paragraphs in my posts, in php (I'm not using any CMS). So my html posts have the next structure:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
<p>Paragraph 6</p>
```

And I want to dynamically add some ad block between paragraphs, for example each 3 paragraphs. So the final html would be something like:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<ad block 1>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
<p>Paragraph 6</p>
<ad block 2>
```

I need some php function that allows me to insert the ad blocks the nth time

```
</p>
```

appears on the string of the post.

The variable in which I have the html of the post I get in this way:

**$article = getArticle($article_id, $user_data['id']);
and the html of the post is in $article['description']**

I need a function like

```
preg_replace('</p>', '</p><adblock>', $article['description']);
```

but that de the replacement on the 3rd ocurrence instead of always.

Comment: firstly please show us the code which currently generates this HTML. Or is it static? Or loaded from a database? It's unclear. You didn't really give any proper context for your question. So the only advice I can give so far is you're probably going to need some kind of loop. Possibly you also need a way to parse HTML, it depends. Beyond that I can't really say what to do precisely.

Comment: I have detailed a little bit more now.

Comment: I would not use a regular expression to try and detect the structure of HTML... instead use a DOM parser

Answer (score 0):

That is easy if you are running the loop. If CMS than I believe you should have a loop.

```
if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
   // your advertise code here
}
```